# Android: best way to load images in background

Tags: android

For my custom list view, I'm using AsyncTask for the web service call and it is working fine.
My List view have a left side image, title, descriptions. the service will return a list of (url, title, desc).

And in my adapter, i'm loading the images using the following code:

```
httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);         
response = httpClient.execute(request);
InputStream is = response.getEntity().getContent();
Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);
```

But I'm not able to see the list view until all the images loaded, I know i'm blocking the UI thread, can anybody suggest the best way to do this without UI blocking.

Thanks,
Venkat Papana

Comment: The concept you need to implement is known as "ListView - Image Lazy Loading" and here is the best example i have ever found: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/541966/android-how-do-i-do-a-lazy-load-of-images-in-listview/3068012#3068012 , just check this.

Answer (score 3):

Use an `AsyncTask` or a `Thread` with a `Handler` like the above answers have noted.

Here is a quick way to get an image resource from a URL:

```
BitmapDrawable bitmapDrawable = new BitmapDrawable(BitmapFactory.decodeStream(new URL("http://example.com/path/to/image/file.jpg").openStream()));
```

Create 1 `AsyncTask`, and in the `doInBackground`, loop through all your image URLS and add each resulting drawable to an icon list, or something

Answer (score 2):

```
new Thread(new Runnable() {

                           @Override
                           public void run() {

                                       httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient(); 
                                       HttpGet request = new HttpGet(url);         
                                       response = httpClient.execute(request);
                                       InputStream is =  response.getEntity().getContent();
                                     msg.obj=is;
                                   mHandler.sendMessage(msg);
                           }
                   }).start();
```

and your handle will be like this

```
mHandler = new Handler() { 
              @Override public void handleMessage(Message msg) { 
                 InputStream is=(InputStream)msg.obj;
                 Drawable drawable = Drawable.createFromStream(is, "src");
                 imgView.setImageDrawable(drawable);

              }
          };
```

Comment: Thank you Sunil, I need to create this new Thread in side an array adapter of a list activity, so i need to create number of threads as per the list elements, in that case how can I know which message is related to specific thread..?

Answer (score 1):

Use an `AsyncTask` for image loading as well. For each loaded image, you can call `publishResults()` from the `doInBackground()` and then have `onProgressUpdate()` put the image in the right place.

Comment: Thank you Heiko, but when i gone through AsyncTask documentation, they mentioned we can call AsyncTask's execute only once; but in my requirement, i need to call AsyncTask for a number of times. how can i?

Comment: Use a new AsyncTask each time  for (int i = 0 ; i < 10 ; i++ ) { new MyAsyncTask().execute(i); }

Comment: Hi Heiko, how do we identify the perticular AsyncTask inside onPostExecute() method, for eg, if (new MyAsyncTaks()).execute(5) finished execution first, then how to update the 5th list item's image view?

Comment: You can pass the respective image view in the constructor of the AsyncTask ( new MyAsyncTask(iv).execute() ) -- or when you want to handle multiple images, pass a list of IV in the constructor and then iterate over them inside the AsyncTask's doInBackground

Answer (score 1):

This is the better way just try.. this is for image load in cardview

```
private class LoadImage extends AsyncTask<String, String, Bitmap> {
    Bitmap bitmap1 = null;
    CurrentVehicleStatus currentVehicleStatus;

    int i;
    @Override
    protected void onPreExecute() {
        super.onPreExecute();
        //Stuff on preexecute

        pDialog = new ProgressDialog(AdminActivity.this);
        pDialog.setTitle("Please wait");
        pDialog.setMessage("Loading data..");
        pDialog.show();

    }
    protected Bitmap doInBackground(String... args) {

           for(int i=0;i<arrayLength;i++) {
          //Your class reference that store your values for adapter
          yourClassReference = yourArrayList.get(i);

            try {
                bitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeStream((InputStream) new URL("Your URL"
                ).getContent());

            } catch (Exception e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
    //this setImage method in data class
      yourArrayList.get(i).setImage(bitmap);

         }

        }


        return bitmap1;
    }

    protected void onPostExecute(Bitmap image) {

        pDialog.dismiss();
    //Notify adapter
        mAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

    }
}
```

is there any doubt comment me